# Why dont chabad say chasal sidur pesach?

Tags: passover-seder-hagada, song-poetry, chabad

Why don't Chabad Chassidim say ''chasal sidur pesach'' at the end of the seder?

Comment: Why should they?

Comment: Because everyone else does

Comment: That's not true. Here's a Haggada that doesn't have it http://mechon-mamre.org/i/3510.htm I've seen many others like that too. Without justification, you can just as easily ask why they don't sing "take me out to the ballgame." Most Rishonim in fact don't list it in what happens at the Seder. Nearly all their lists just end with the 4th cup. Why should Chabad follow this newfangled custom?

Comment: I wonder who uses that hagada

Comment: Most Ashkenazi Jews said that paragraph in the Yotzrot for Shabbat haGadol http://mobile.tora.ws/html/2220223-6.html

Comment: Here you can find plenty of Haggadot from 500-700 years ago. Tell me how many have "chasal sidur pesach" at the end http://hebrewmanuscripts.org/

Comment: my question was not which haggadas say it and which don't I want to know why today do o only chabad not say it

Comment: What the site is looking for is a better justification of the question. So if you wrote: Every other Hagada currently used for the Seder that I have seen includes Chasal Sidur Pesach except for the Chabad one. Why do they not say it? It would go over better. See [here](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1714/i-dont-think-were-explaining-sourcing-properly-to-new-users) and other related questions on meta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like is stated explicitly in the [Rebbe's commentary](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=15765&st=&pgnum=56) at the end of the Haggadah to this question, it is because like with all the Moadim, the influence of the order of Pesach radiates eternally into each and every day of the year. It is not finished and it does not cease.

Comment: So why does everyone else say it @Yaacov Deane

Comment: @Menachem You should direct that to those who say. Ask them what they have been taught.

Comment: @menachem Probably because the Seder is finished. Yom Kippur should influence everything you do that year, but no one keeps on fasting when it's done.